# Linq query that returns a summary of transaction

Tags: c#, linq

hi i have a table which keeps track of several transactions made by several employees and these are the fields and the same employee could have made several transactions
how do i write a linq query that gets a record that contains the total transaction details of each employee?

the result should have uniqe employee id with total pending amount and total Receipt amount

```
EmployeeID|PendingAmount|RecieptAmount
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group records by `EmployeeID` and then calculate all you need for each employee group:

```
from e in db.Employess
group e by e.EmployeeID into g
select new {
   EmployeeID = g.Key,
   PendingAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PendingAmount), // total pending amount
   RecieptAmount = g.Sum(x => x.RecieptAmount) // total reciept amount
}
```